# ReSharper 5 disable resolve view

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I just did a fresh installation of Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and ReSharper 5. But now ran into the following situation;

```
return View("~/Plugin/Plugin.Product.dll/Plugin.Product.Views.CreateProduct.ascx");
```

From a controller i'm returning a view a shown above. ReSharper 5 is trying to resolve this view, but can't find it. Which is explainable in my situation. What i want is to disable the option for ReSharper to try and resolve the views. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can disable ASP.NET MVC resolving at all. See ReSharper->Options->ASP.NET.

Second, you can disable resolving exactly in that place, where you don't need it by special comment. See Quick Fix available on unresolved view.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Was able to disable it by clicking the ReSharper simbol at the beginning of the line and then choose 'Inspection Options'